# Redirect Loop on images when using CDN's redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, cdn

I am having a hard time figuring out what is wrong.

As soon as I add my CDN's code to my .htaccess to redirect static content to the CDN, it results in a redirect loop on those files.

I noticed they keep redirecting to themselves instead of loading the file.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force no www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain.com/$0 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://domain.com/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrite domain.com/p/contact to index.php?p=contact
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

My CDN's code that breaks the site:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A0

    # Set up caching for 1 week(s)
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|ppt|rar|zip|tar|gz|tgz|bz2|flv|avi|mov|wmv|mp3|wav)$">
        ExpiresDefault A604800
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Set up caching for 1 day(s)
    <FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
        ExpiresDefault A86400
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Set up caching for 1 hour(s)
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        ExpiresDefault A3600
        Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Force no caching for dynamic files
    <FilesMatch ".(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
        ExpiresActive Off
        Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Via}   !\.s\.worldcdn\.com
    # Flash wont work on cross-domain by default
    RewriteCond $1            !^.swf$ [NC]
    RewriteCond $1            "\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|ico|js|css|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|ppt|rar|zip|tar|gz|tgz|bz2|flv|avi|mov|wmv|mp3|wav|xml|txt)$" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)           http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Subdomains, CDN etc. are all set up correctly.

Maybe it's a problem with the CDN?
Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From  Flag `L`: [Apache <sup>Docs</sup>: flag_l](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) **:**

> If you are using RewriteRule in either `.htaccess` files or in `<Directory>` sections, it is important to have some understanding of how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or  section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the request process to start over.

---

Since, rewritten request is handed back to the URL parsing engine, after redirect from the last `RewriteRule` here,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Via}   !\.s\.worldcdn\.com
    # Flash wont work on cross-domain by default
    RewriteCond $1            !^.swf$ [NC]
    RewriteCond $1            "\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|ico|js|css|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|ppt|rar|zip|tar|gz|tgz|bz2|flv|avi|mov|wmv|mp3|wav|xml|txt)$" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)           http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

---

either 
edit this line to :

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)           http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

or,

if you want to have the URI change at the browser as well, add the first `RewriteCond`

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !cdn\.domain\.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Via}   !\.s\.worldcdn\.com
    RewriteCond $1            !^.swf$ [NC]
    RewriteCond $1            "\.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|ico|js|css|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|ppt|rar|zip|tar|gz|tgz|bz2|flv|avi|mov|wmv|mp3|wav|xml|txt)$" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)           http://cdn.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
```